# connection Failed : Io exception Size Data Unit(SDU)mismatch

Tags: java, runtime-error, network-connection

I am new to Aqua Data Studio. This is the first time I am using it. At the time of registering a new server I am getting this error:

> connection Failed : Io exception Size Data Unit(SDU)mismatch.

Can any one suggest what is needed to correct the fault?

Comment: Were you able to fix the Aqua Data Studio connection issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross check the Type of Data base you selected while registering the database

If there is a mismatch, this error may come

2) check if the drivers are properly copied to the Lib folder under Aqua data studio

Answer (score 0):

This is the link for the AquaFold Oracle JDBC configuration : https://www.aquaclusters.com/app/home/project/public/aquadatastudio/wikibook/Documentation16/page/Oracle-JDBC-Drivers/Oracle-JDBC-Drivers 
From the error message, I believe you are trying to connect to Oracle.
Can you confirm the Database version you are trying to connect to ? 
What Server Type are you selecting from the Register Server Dialog?